# jQuery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery ui from google repository. I'm getting the data in the following format:

```
[{name:"test", param1:"test"},{name:"test2", param1:"test2"}...]
```

but the jQuery autocomplete are searching in the field named "label"
So how could I change the "label" to "name" because I want to filter the information where the name fields are contains the typed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading between the lines on your post, I see that you can't edit the portion that's providing the data to the page, so you have to manipulate what you have. **but it would be so much easier to just change what's being provided to match what you need**

I believe to get this to work you're going to have to rework the options in the source callback, using the request object, and creating a item on each child that matches the one you want. So something like:

```
$( selector ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    response( function(data){
      for(key in data){
        data[key].label = data[key].name;
      }
      return data;
    } );
  }
});
```

But I'm not 100% sure about this code.

***alternately*** you could override the "filter" function here:

```
$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
escapeRegex: function( value ) {
    return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
},
filter: function(array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
    return $.grep( array, function(value) {
        return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
    });
}
});
```

to change the behavior to use what you're getting back. But I would call that bad design/implementation.